# Destoying prefab, when the player hit it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, destroy, gameobject

Is it possible to destroy only one clone of the prefab, (I don't know it's exact name, sorry) when the player  object (Sphere) hits it?

```
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") 
    {
        Destroy (GoldCube);
    }
}
```

The "goldCube" is the game object name, which has a prefab called "GoldCube". And I want to destroy only one clone of it, when the main object "Sphere" (tag name: "Player") hits it.

Comment: Is the script on the gold cube or the player?

Comment: Yes it is on in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the script is on the GoldCube,

Instead of

```
Destroy(GoldCube);
```

try using

```
Destroy(gameObject);
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

If this script is on the player(which in this case, it isn't),

```
Destroy(other.gameObject);
```

[Documentation for Destroy](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html)